# Допускает ли лицензия Qt вмешательство в набор поставляемых файлов?

Tags: windows, qt, qml

При сборке `Qt` приложения под Windows с `Qml` интерфейсом утилита `windeployqt` подтягивает много файлов, связанных с обеспечением работы `qml` интерфейса. Это каталоги

```
- QtGraphicalEffects
- QtQml
- QtQuick
- QtQuick.2
```

по количеству их около 700 штук. Навскидку, 95% из них не нужны. Если удалить ненужные, то программа нормально работает. По крайней мере проверял на неиспользуемых `QtGraphicalEffects` и `QtQuick/Dialogs`.

Основной вопрос - допускает ли лицензия Qt такое вмешательство в набор поставляемых файлов?

Может есть готовые решения для подтягивания только нужных файлов?

Сейчас `windeployqt` вызывается так:

```
 windeployqt ..release\myapplication.exe --qmldir ..\src\qml --no-translations
```

Comment: да, насколько мне известно, если только эти файлы не модифицировались. Но я бы несколько раз перепроверил, что утилита windeployqt не ошиблась. Если есть сомнения, можно сделать две версии - одна полная, и одна сокращенная.